# How can you divide value of one dataTable column by value of label text?

Tags: c#, math, datatable

**Question**

How can I have column "Days" populate the results of column "Hours" divided by label25.Text?

**Code**

Below is the code I'm attempting to accomplish this.  I'm thinking the issue is within the foreach portion.

```
            dataGridView4.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(String));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Hours", typeof(String));
            dt2.Columns.Add("PerDiem", typeof(String));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Days", typeof(decimal)).Expression = "[Hours]/" + label25.Text;
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn type = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            var list10 = new List<string>() { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry"};
            type.DataSource = list10;
            type.HeaderText = "Type";
            type.DataPropertyName = "Type";
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn hours = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            hours.HeaderText = "Hours";
            hours.DataPropertyName = "Hours";
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn perdiem = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            var list11 = new List<string>() { "YES", "NO"};
            perdiem.DataSource = list11;
            perdiem.HeaderText = "PerDiem";
            perdiem.DataPropertyName = "PerDiem";
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn days = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            days.HeaderText = "Days";
            days.DataPropertyName = "Days";
            dataGridView4.DataSource = dt2;
            dataGridView4.Columns.AddRange(type, hours, perdiem, days);
            dataGridView4.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            type.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            perdiem.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Any help would be appreciated!!  Thank you in advance.

**Update**

```
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Hours", typeof(decimal));
            dt2.Columns.Add("HoursInAWorkingDay", typeof(decimal));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Days", typeof(decimal)).Expression = "[Hours]/[HoursInAWorkingDay]";
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn hours = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            hours.HeaderText = "Hours";
            hours.DataPropertyName = "Hours";
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn perdiem = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn hoursinaworkingday = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            var list13 = new List<string>() { "8", "10", "12", "14" };
            hoursinaworkingday.DataSource = list13;
            hoursinaworkingday.HeaderText = "Work Day";
            hoursinaworkingday.DataPropertyName = "Work Day";
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn days = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            days.HeaderText = "Days";
            days.DataPropertyName = "Days";
```

Made the suggested changes and I'm still falling short.  Unfortunately the Days column is not populating a value when entering data in Hours and/or Selecting an option from HoursInAWorkDay.  Please help.  I know we're close.

Comment: `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn perdiem = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn hoursinaworkingday = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();` is a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
dt2.Columns.Add("Days", typeof(String));
```

To

```
dt2.Columns.Add("Days", typeof(decimal)).Expression = "[Hours]/" + label25.Text;
```

Also make your Hours column typeof(decimal) and remove the for loop from the bottom of the code

The days column is now read only and autopopulates based on the hours. If you want it to be variable (ie to update if you change label25.Text) you should instead put a column in the datatable for the divisor and bind label25 to it

Other tips:

- String is the default type of a column; you don't need to specify it
- You could make your life much easier by adding a DataSet object to your project and doing all this in there; it creates strongly typed datatables that are much easier to work with in every way

---

Please also name your controls and variables properly - renaming a control/naming a var an apt name takes a couple of seconds. Eventually you will rue the day you wrote the code to be full of meaningless names like "datatable 2, list 10, label 25" because it makes it incredibly difficult to maintain; you're going to constantly have to look up what is what..

You do seem to appreciate the notion of naming some things sensibly (you've called your days and hours Columns "days" and "hours" rather than "decimal1" and "decimal2" - extend the notion out to every line of code you write) - it makes it easier for other developers to help you too

Comment: Caius to the rescue again.  Thank you.  With trying to understand the code, I've tried to limit the renaming controls and variables until I can fully grasp what the code means.  However, I am beginning to understand the value and necessity.  Also, when replacing as you instructed, I'm getting the following error: System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column [label25].'

Comment: Oh it'll certainly help understand what the code means if you have e.g. `.Expression = "[Hours]/" + hoursInAWorkingDay` :)

Comment: Your error "System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column [label25]" means that `label25.Text` literally contains the text "label25" and datatable hence thinks you have another column called label25. When you asked your question, I was under the impression that `label25.Text` contained a numeric string like "8", which would have meant the expression as a whole was like `"[Hours]/8"` which the datatable can evaluate. Ensure that your expression can be evaluated. You may only use column names that are present in the table like Hours, constants like 8, and some functions (read the docs)

Comment: If you're thinking that `Expression = "[Hours]/" + label25.Text` means that datatable will constantly update based on whatever label25.Text is now, know that this *isnt* the case; that line of code is turned into a string one time, using whatever value is present in label25.Text at the time it is executed. It becomes the fixed text of a formula that datatable executes repeatedly. If you want divisor to be variable then add another column to the datatable eg add a decimal column called HoursInAWorkingDay and then set the expression to eg `.Expression = "[Hours]/[HoursInAWorkingDay]"`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netcore-3.1 - docs for Expression property

Comment: Tried what you suggested and I'm still falling short (please see update in post).  I trimmed some of the "fat" of the code to only what was relevant.  Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It looks nearly right, though I'd maybe use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>` for the combo and set a DisplayMember of "Key" And ValueMember of "Value" so that the combo is poking a decimal value into a decimal column rather than a string

Comment: Also the datapropertyname of the hours in a working day combo seems wrong. It needs to put its value in HoursInAWorkingDay, not [Work Day]. When a combo is having a list of items but setting a value on another place, the DataPropertyName shall be the column name in the other place, the DataSource shall be the list of items, the DisplayMember shall be the column to show in the box and the ValueMember shall be the column whose value is looked up/pushed into the other place

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a separate answer because your edit actually asks a separate question (how to bind up a combo so it properly edits a table column, versus how to make a table column auto calc a value based on two other columns)

This is a complete fixed code, nicely spaced out/arranged and commented so you can look over it and read what it's doing. You could make a new project, double click the blank form it create and replace the Form1_Load code with this. Note that (with the exception of Form1) I've named variables slightly more sensibly than "dt2", "list13" ;):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set up table
        DataTable timesheet = new DataTable();
        timesheet.Columns.Add("Hours", typeof(decimal));
        timesheet.Columns.Add("HoursInAWorkingDay", typeof(decimal));
        //Add creates a column and returns it, so we can set the expression on the return value, without needing to dig it out of the column collection again
        timesheet.Columns.Add("Days", typeof(decimal)).Expression = "[Hours]/[HoursInAWorkingDay]";

        //set up column for Hours - dont really need this, it would autogenerate
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn hours = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        hours.HeaderText = "Hours";
        hours.DataPropertyName = "Hours";

        //set up column for HoursInAWorkingDay
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn hoursinaworkingday = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

        //make array of decimal values, then use LINQ to turn them into a list of objects that have a `string Dis` and a `decimal Val` property
        //these will be used during binding
        var hiawd = new[] { 8m, 10m, 12m, 14m }.Select(s => new { Dis = $"{s:0}h", Val = s }).ToList();
        hoursinaworkingday.HeaderText = "Work Day";
        hoursinaworkingday.DataPropertyName = "HoursInAWorkingDay"; //the column in dt2 that changing the combo shall edit
        hoursinaworkingday.DisplayMember = "Dis"; //show the Dis property in the combo, e.g. the string "8h"
        hoursinaworkingday.ValueMember = "Val"; //use the Val property of the item selected (e.g. the decimal 8) when setting the HoursInAWorkingDay
        hoursinaworkingday.DataSource = hiawd; //the list of values to use for items in the combo. tip: set datasource last

        //it is important to appreciate that the combo connects the datatable to the list. it:
        //1. reads the dt row's HoursInAWorkingDay, 
        //2. finds the read value in the Val property of a list item, 
        //3. shows that item by the Dis property. 
        //4. when the user picks a new item the value of the new item's Val 
        //   property is written back to the dt HoursInAWorkingDay column

        //set up column for Days - dont really need this, it would autogenerate
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn days = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        days.HeaderText = "Days";
        days.DataPropertyName = "Days";

        var dgv = new DataGridView();
        dgv.Columns.Add(hours);
        dgv.Columns.Add(hoursinaworkingday);
        dgv.Columns.Add(days);
        this.Controls.Add(dgv);
        dgv.DataSource = timesheet;
        dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Caius is the bee's knees!!");